# How to add an input_renderer for a custom customer attribute?

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, adminhtml, adminform

I added a custom attribute for `customer` collection named `customer_mode`.

It have 2 values `first`, and `second` in the following maner:

```
$data = array(
'customer' => array(
    'customer_mode' => array(
        'label'      => 'Customer Mode',
        'sort_order' => 285,
        'required'   => false,
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => 1 // First
    )
));
```

In back office admin area I want to show this field not as int but as an custom input type (select box).

I added the Input renderer:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Company_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Form_Renderer_CustomerModeType
 *
 * @author Alexandru Olaru <alxolr@gmail.com>
 */
class Company_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Form_Renderer_Mode extends
    Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->setValues(
            array(
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('company_customer')->__('First'),
                    'value' => 1,
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('company_customer')->__('Second'),
                    'value' => 2,
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**Now my problem is what value should I put on the `input_renderer` ?**

```
$data = array(
    'customer' => array(
        'customer_mode' => array(
            'label'      => 'Customer Mode',
            'sort_order' => 285,
            'required'   => false,
            'type' => 'int',
            'default' => 1,
            'input_renderer' => **????**
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: someone has a solution to this ? I have a customer cusotm attribute and I want to render the value with some "hack" before...

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140715)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140715)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You will need to create customer attribute this way**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customer_mode",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Customer Mode",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "customer/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customer_mode");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Create your own model class like

```
Namespace_Module_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Customeroptions
```

Add below functions in that class

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (is_null($this->_options)) {
        $this->_options = array(

            array(
                "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("First"),
                "value" =>  1
            ),

            array(
                "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Second"),
                "value" =>  2
            ),

        );
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

/**
 * Retrieve option array
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptionArray()
{
    $_options = array();
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
    }
    return $_options;
}

/**
 * Get a text for option value
 *
 * @param string|integer $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $options = $this->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option["value"] == $value) {
            return $option["label"];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your setup class should be `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` in your config.xml

```
<customerattribute_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Namespace_Module</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
</customerattribute_setup>
```

Comment: A nice solution but i wanted to use the custom render...

Answer (score 0):

Customer attributes don't have an `input_renderer`.

You got to set custom renderer
(it uses interface `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface`)
for a form element in your form block class.